# Full Screen (F11 mode not ESC mode) in IE 11 using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress

Please look at my following code for full-screen

```
function toggleFullScreen() {
    if (!document.fullscreenElement &&    // alternative standard method
        !document.mozFullScreenElement && !document.webkitFullscreenElement && !document.msFullscreenElement) {  // current working methods
        if (document.documentElement.requestFullscreen) {
            document.documentElement.requestFullscreen();
        } else if (document.documentElement.msRequestFullscreen) {
            document.documentElement.msRequestFullscreen();
        } else if (document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {
            document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen();
        } else if (document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
            document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
        }
    } else {
        if (document.exitFullscreen) {
            document.exitFullscreen();
        } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
            document.msExitFullscreen();
        } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
            document.mozCancelFullScreen();
        } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
            document.webkitExitFullscreen();
        }
    }
}
```

This code is working fine. But problem is that when i press "Esc" it is going in normal mode.

Basically what i want is when we press "F11" then it is going full screen and it is not going back in normal mode even after pressing "Esc".

So, i want to know how to press "F11" using jQuery ?

Comment: Sorry if it sounded rude, what I wanted to say was that it would be a terrible idea for a web browser to let javascript prevent full screen mode from escaping.

Comment: not like that - when you will go in full screen then if you press reload then full screen will go out. but when you will do full screen with "F11" and then reload page then full screen will not go to normal. That is my intense. Anyways i found the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got solution,

I have added this condition in starting of my function:

```
var hasAX = "ActiveXObject" in window;
if (hasAX)
    var wscript = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
    if (wscript !== null) {
        wscript.SendKeys("{F11}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Though this is not more working with latest version.